# can't install steam on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dependencies, steam

I am not able to install `steam`.

Firstly, from the Ubuntu Software Centre it fails to install and I get the following;

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam64: Depends: steam (= 1.0.0.27ubuntu1)`
```

but it is a virtual package.

Then when I read another method using Terminal to update, clear steam, then install steam, I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try to upgrade video/graphics driver (NVIDIA/ATI) and restart the OS,

after that run the command :- sudo apt-get update and follow this link:-

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve

here are all details of intel and other drivers of dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I succeeded with;                        wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
  sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
  sudo gdebi steam.deb